# Wordpress Login via www and non-www

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, authentication

My Wordpress installation appears to only like logging people in using the www. subdomain and forces the www. subdomain for most links.  However I would like it so when someone logs into my site at www.mysite.com and mysite.com, it logs them in in both places on wordpress.  Among other reasons this is because my wordpress installation is riddled with www and non-www links.

In PHP this is normally done by leaving the "domain" parameter of setcookie() empty/null or for older browsers, specifying a dot prior to the domain, IE ".mysite.com".

Is there any way to get wordpress to perform this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have one or the other.

1. Under 'General Settings' in your WP control panel, specify your address in your preferred way, ie. with or without 'www'.
2. Assuming you are on a server running apache: create one of the following `.htaccess` files in the root of your site.

```
# Redirect www urls to non-www
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.yoursite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

```
# Redirect non-www urls to www
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.yoursite\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: "You can only have one or the other.", why?  I have a custom login script I programmed that works with both...